# Virtual env won't run - setuptools pip failed with error code 2

Tags: python, django, pip, virtualenv

I thought maybe it's because there are spaces in the directory, specifically the folder "Program Files (x86)".

People have suggested this error is a known bug in the newer virtualenv versions but I don't know how to install older versions. Apparently version 1.10.1 works but I don't know how to install it..

I'm running windows 7,
pip 6.0.8,
Django 1.7.7,
virtualenv 12.0.7,
Python 3.4.3

When trying to run virtualenv env command this happens..

```
G:\Program Files (x86)\Python34>virtualenv env
Using base prefix 'G:\\Program Files (x86)\\Python34'
New python executable in env\Scripts\python.exe
Installing setuptools, pip...
  Complete output from command "G:\Program Files (x8...v\Scripts\python.exe" -c "import sys, pip; sys...d\"] + sys.argv[1:]))" setuptools pip:
  Ignoring indexes: https://pypi.python.org/simple
Collecting setuptools
  This repository located at None is not a trusted host, if this repository is available via HTTPS it is recommend to use HTTPS instead, otherwise you may silence this warning with '--trusted-host None'.
  DEPRECATION: Implicitly allowing locations which are not hosted at a secure origin is deprecated and will require the use of --trusted-host in the future.
  This repository located at None is not a trusted host, if this repository is available via HTTPS it is recommend to use HTTPS instead, otherwise you may silence this warning with '--trusted-host None'.
  This repository located at None is not a trusted host, if this repository is available via HTTPS it is recommend to use HTTPS instead, otherwise you may silence this warning with '--trusted-host None'.
  This repository located at None is not a trusted host, if this repository is available via HTTPS it is recommend to use HTTPS instead, otherwise you may silence this warning with '--trusted-host None'.
  This repository located at None is not a trusted host, if this repository is available via HTTPS it is recommend to use HTTPS instead, otherwise you may silence this warning with '--trusted-host None'.
  This repository located at None is not a trusted host, if this repository is available via HTTPS it is recommend to use HTTPS instead, otherwise you may silence this warning with '--trusted-host None'.
  This repository located at None is not a trusted host, if this repository is available via HTTPS it is recommend to use HTTPS instead, otherwise you may silence this warning with '--trusted-host None'.
  This repository located at None is not a trusted host, if this repository is available via HTTPS it is recommend to use HTTPS instead, otherwise you may silence this warning with '--trusted-host None'.
  This repository located at None is not a trusted host, if this repository is available via HTTPS it is recommend to use HTTPS instead, otherwise you may silence this warning with '--trusted-host None'.
  Exception:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "G:\Program Files (x86)\Python34\lib\site-packages\virtualenv_support\pip-6.0.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl\pip\basecommand.py", line 232, in main
      status = self.run(options, args)
    File "G:\Program Files (x86)\Python34\lib\site-packages\virtualenv_support\pip-6.0.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl\pip\commands\install.py", line 339, in run
      requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
    File "G:\Program Files (x86)\Python34\lib\site-packages\virtualenv_support\pip-6.0.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl\pip\req\req_set.py", line 333, in prepare_files
      upgrade=self.upgrade,
    File "G:\Program Files (x86)\Python34\lib\site-packages\virtualenv_support\pip-6.0.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl\pip\index.py", line 351, in find_requirement
      for page in self._get_pages(locations, req):
    File "G:\Program Files (x86)\Python34\lib\site-packages\virtualenv_support\pip-6.0.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl\pip\index.py", line 566, in _get_pages
      page = self._get_page(location, req)
    File "G:\Program Files (x86)\Python34\lib\site-packages\virtualenv_support\pip-6.0.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl\pip\index.py", line 783, in _get_page
      return HTMLPage.get_page(link, req, session=self.session)
    File "G:\Program Files (x86)\Python34\lib\site-packages\virtualenv_support\pip-6.0.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl\pip\index.py", line 872, in get_page
      "Cache-Control": "max-age=600",
    File "G:\Program Files (x86)\Python34\lib\site-packages\virtualenv_support\pip-6.0.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 473, in get
      return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
    File "G:\Program Files (x86)\Python34\lib\site-packages\virtualenv_support\pip-6.0.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl\pip\download.py", line 365, in request
      return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
    File "G:\Program Files (x86)\Python34\lib\site-packages\virtualenv_support\pip-6.0.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 461, in request
      resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
    File "G:\Program Files (x86)\Python34\lib\site-packages\virtualenv_support\pip-6.0.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 567, in send
      adapter = self.get_adapter(url=request.url)
    File "G:\Program Files (x86)\Python34\lib\site-packages\virtualenv_support\pip-6.0.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 646, in get_adapter
      raise InvalidSchema("No connection adapters were found for '%s'" % url)
  pip._vendor.requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for 'g:\Program'

----------------------------------------
...Installing setuptools, pip...done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\Program Files (x86)\Python34\lib\runpy.py", line 170, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "G:\Program Files (x86)\Python34\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "G:\Program Files (x86)\Python34\Scripts\virtualenv.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "G:\Program Files (x86)\Python34\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 825, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
  File "G:\Program Files (x86)\Python34\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 993, in create_environment
    install_wheel(to_install, py_executable, search_dirs)
  File "G:\Program Files (x86)\Python34\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 961, in install_wheel
    'PIP_NO_INDEX': '1'
  File "G:\Program Files (x86)\Python34\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 903, in call_subprocess
    % (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command "G:\Program Files (x8...v\Scripts\python.exe" -c "import sys, pip; sys...d\"] + sys.argv[1:]))" setuptools pip failed with error code 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Uninstalled Python 3.4 and installed Python 2.7 to the default directory "C:/Python27". Reinstalled pip and virtualenv.

Now when creating a virtualenv everything works fine. I would guess it was because of the spaces in the directory!

Comment: I have tried it with Python 3.4 itself, it seems space is the problem :-(. After re-installing without space things are working